# Codeigniter event calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter, calendar

I'm building a webapp in Codeigniter version 3. I'd like to add an event calendar. Therefore I used the default Codeigniter calendar library.

I can display the calendar and even show multiple events a day.

But I also need to show events which starts a day and ends some days later. By now, I create a single event for each day, which is in the timespan. But I like to show this multi-day event in the calendar, so that the visitor can see, that this events takes multiple days. I'd like to add a colorful bar over each day, the events takes. So that there is a color bar. How can I do this?

Comment: What code do you currently have for this?  What does it output?  Is there anything else you have tried?

Comment: Since your task request comes from aesthetic needs mostly, consider [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io) as possible solution.